# What are the differences/similarities between a project manager and a functional manager?

Tags: terminology

How can we describe them separately according their roles?  Actually I am a new student; I don't have proper knowledge about this. Please guide me as a basic student.

Comment: Are they managing a project or a business function? That’s the core of it.

Answer (score 1):

Although there's a broadly accepted definition of what a Project Manager is, I'm afraid there isn't such canonical answer for what a "Functional Manager" is supposed to do. In most of the cases, it'll strongly depend on the environment or context the question comes from.

Potential definitions:

- A person responsible for a given *function within a company* (Sales manager, marketing manager)
- A person responsible for a given *function within a project* (Development manager, test manager)
- A person responsible for ensuring functional requirements are properly tracked (a kind of Functional analyst lead)

Another aspects to consider is that usually a function is something *constant over time* whereas a project is something with a *(planned) end date*.

Comment: I don't think you would say a Functional Manager is someone responsible "for a given function within a project"... that sounds too close to an Individual Contributor role, which a Functional Manager is not.

Comment: Again, environment dependant. Above list contain possible different interpretations of the same role.

Comment: And in our projet (100+ people) there's a Dev Manager, a Test manager and a Release manager. All managers in their own area.

Answer (score 1):

PMBOK makes a clear distinction between these roles; just look to that. **Project Manager**: person assigned by the performing organization to lead the team that is responsible for achieving the project objectives.

**Functional Manager**: person with management authority over an organizational unit within a functional organization. The manager of any group that actually makes a product or performs a service. Sometimes called a line manager.

Another way to look at it is the Functional Manager always has a "home base" within the company, *e.g.,* Engineering department. The Project Manager doesn't necessarily have a home base because there might not be a Project Management department, per se.

SOURCE: https://medium.com/@pmpeople/the-10-roles-in-project-management-de52e382edd9